# Prevent Windows 7 prompt format USB HDD

Tags: windows-7, windows, truecrypt

I am running Windows 7. I have a USB HDD 100% formatted with a Trucypt partition. When I insert the drive into my system, Windows asks if I would like to format the drive, each time I insert the drive.

So how do I turn this prompt off? If so, I would prefer it be applied globally (e.g. no more prompts for any other drives).

Since its an invisible partition unless mounted with Trucypt, Windows is always going to think nothing is there and continue to prompt me. I don't want to hit enter on the keyboard a few times by mistake doing something else and have it to go through the process. I'll lose everything. It is all backed up BTW. Will just be inconvienient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encrypt the device instead of a partition, this does not occur. Other than that, you can perform the following procedure to stop it from happening:

- Connect the drive to the computer
- Go to `Start` > `Computer` > `Right click` > `Manage item`
- Select `Storage` > `Disk management`. Select the encrypted drive, right click on it, and choose the `Change drive letter and Paths` item.
- Select the drive letter and click "remove".

Comment: Great that seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. You can mark a question as solved with the tick icon on the left. :)